# Not able to write beamSql data to BigQuery

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to write beamSql data to BigQuery as shown below :

```java
final_out1.apply(BigQueryIO.<TableRow>Write
    .named("Write")
    .to("my-project:data_id1.tables_test")
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

I'm getting error on named(), the error :

```
The method named(String) is undefined for the type BigQueryIO.Write
```

Any idea what this means ?

**EDIT**
The format function that I defined :

```java
final_out1.apply(BigQueryIO.<TableRow>write()
    .withSchema(schema)
    .to("beta-194409:data_id1.tables_test"));
    /*  .withFormatFunction(fin -> new TableRow().
                                 set("SalesComponent", fin.getSalesComponent()).
                                 set("DuetoValue", fin.getDuetoValue()).
                                 set("ModelIteration", fin.getMo//delIteration()))  */
    //.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE).withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about `withFormatFunction()`?

Comment: I have implemented Format function and its working fine. The data is getting written into BigQuery.

Comment: I do have a little doubt, but that I'll post as a new question. Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method `named()` for class `BigQueryIO.Write` so this error makes sense.

You can specify a transform name as the first parameter of the `apply()` method.

```java
final_out1.apply("Write", BigQueryIO.<TableRow>.write()
    .to("my-project:data_id1.tables_test")
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

Note: Use `BigQueryIO.write()` instead of `BigQueryIO.Write`.

Comment: I did that but now its asking for a format function :   : A function must be provided to convert type into a TableRow. use BigQueryIO.Write.withFormatFunction to provide a formatting function